# C++ WM_LBUTTONDOWN not triggering when using WM_NCHITTEST

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, click, window

I am using win32 to create a window with custom titlbar and border. My problem is that when i am using `WM_NCHITTEST` `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` doesn't get triggered on clicking events. I receive the clicking event when i am not using `WM_NCHITTEST`. I am not getting any errors.

I have tried removing the code in `WM_NCHITTEST` so i only `return 0`. I have tried removing `WM_NCHITTEST` then `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` works but i need both to work.

```
//Declaring before switch
int x, y;
RECT rect;
int iTitlebarY = 20;

case WM_NCHITTEST: {
        GetWindowRect(hwnd, &rect);

        x = GET_X_LPARAM(lParam);
        y = GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam);

        if (y <= rect.top + iTitlebarY) {
            return HTCAPTION;
        }
        //Some more code for resizing...

        return 0;
        }

    case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
        //Never gets triggered
        //Do something...
```

I expected that i recieved the mouse click because i do when i don't use `WM_NCHITTEST`.

Comment: you need return value returned by `DefWindowProc` function here or return `HTCLIENT` sometime. `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` will be only when `HTCLIENT` returned by `WM_NCHITTEST` but you never return it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from [`WM_LBUTTONDOWN`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-lbuttondown) message

> Posted when the user presses the left mouse button while the cursor is
>   **in the client area** of a window

compare this with [`WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-nclbuttondown) message

> Posted when the user presses the left mouse button while the cursor is
>   **within the nonclient area** of a window

but which part of windows is **client area** ? for determine this exist [`WM_NCHITTEST`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-nchittest) message:

> Sent to a window in order to determine what part of the window
>   corresponds to a particular screen coordinate

only if you return `HTCLIENT` in response to `WM_NCHITTEST` - you in a client area. and only in this case you got `WM_LBUTTONDOWN`

but you never return `HTCLIENT` in response to `WM_NCHITTEST` - you always return 0, which is mean `HTNOWHERE`

so instead return `HTNOWHERE` you need call `DefWindowProc` and return it value:

```
//return HTNOWHERE;
return DefWindowProc(hWnd, Msg, wParam, lParam);
```

or yourself somehow detect what is client area in your case and return `HTCLIENT` when cursor is in the client area of a window